# C# LINQ Debugging through an IEnumerable extension method

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

I am trying to step through the following IEnumerable extension method that I called DumpIt. The debugger will not step through it. How can I get the debugger to step into this extension method?

My unit test:

```
[Test]
        public void TestDumpIt()
        {
            var words =
                new string[] {"   KOOKABURRA", "Frogmouth", "kingfisher   ", "loon", "merganser"};

            var result = words
                .DumpIt(d => "original: " + d)
                .Select(word => word.Trim())
                .DumpIt(d => "trimmed: " + d)
                .Select(word => word.ToLower())
                .DumpIt(d => "lower cased: " + d)
                .Where(word => word.StartsWith("k"))
                .DumpIt(d => "starts with k: " + d)
                .OrderBy(word => word)
                .DumpIt(d => "orderd: " + d);
        }
```

The extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DumpIt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input,
    Func<T, string> toString
    )
{
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        Output.ActivePane.Activate();
        Output.ActivePane.OutputString(
            ShowWhiteSpace ? '[' + toString(item) + ']' : toString(item));

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The debugger won't stop on break points on the extension method body itself?

Comment: Start with a make clean, and then rebuild the whole thing.  Sometimes one of the debugging files doesn't get updated, is corrupted, is out of sync, etc. and the program works, it just can't debug quite right.  Side note; it's considered good practice to only call the selector function on each item once.  That's easy enough to do here; just save the results to a variable once and print them twice rather than calculating it twice.

Comment: I see you were playing around with the code from my [old article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/) on LINQ debugging. I just did a sequel to that article--6 years later(!)--that takes debugging LINQ to the next level with the help of a neat Visual Studio extension--see [LINQ Debugging and Visualization](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/linq-debugging-visualization/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `yield`, you are using delayed execution.  The other LINQ methods you are using use delayed execution as well.  The DumpIt method won't actually get called until you start enumerating your `result` in `TestDumpIt`.  If you want to see the code get called, you need to enumerate the enumerable.  For example, you could just add a `result.ToList()` at the end to force enumeration.

Comment: Duh on my part! Thanks Matt - that fixed it!